# Can ricotta cheese be frozen? If yes then how long it keep in freezer?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, cheese

Can ricotta cheese be frozen to store for a long time.If yes than how long we keep ricotta in freezer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend freezing ricotta as-is. My concern is the freeze-thaw cycle would deteriorate the lovely delicate texture of the curds.

However, freezing a ricotta filling (example: a spinach ricotta filling for a pasta shell or cannelloni) seems to work well (bound with egg, breadcrumbs, parmesan, spinach, etc).